# Did provincial elections occur in 1934 in the provinces of Punjab and Bengal?

Tags: political-history, india, british-empire, government, election

I was reading about elections in British India that happened as per the rules of the Government of India Act, 1919. From 1920 till 1934, a total of five elections were conducted i.e. 1920, 1923, 1926, 1930 & 1934 at both the levels - Province as well as Imperial Legislative Council. While finding sources I came across all but found nothing relating to the Punjab 1934 Provincial Election or the Bengal 1934 Provincial Election, but Madras Provincial elections were conducted in 1934.

Since I'm not able to find any source, was there no election conducted in either Punjab or Bengal during 1934? If so, what was the reason?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1930_Punjab_Legislative_Council_election says that "The Council was given the extension of about 3 years in its three years term and was dissolved on 10 November 1936"

Comment: Thank You so much i appreciate that, but what was the reason for granting that extension?